# Mudar fonte de texto de APP android

Tags: android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo um APP em Android no Android Developer Tools.
gostaria de saber como mudar a fonte de texto que é padrão do Android para a fonte Museo.otf, e como aplicar a todos os TextViews.
agradeço desde já

Answer (score 10):

Existe uma série de passos a realizar para uma correcta implementação de tipos de letra não padrão numa aplicação, bem como algumas considerações a ter.

Segue em baixo uma explicação compreensiva sobre a implementação de tipos de letra numa aplicação Android:

1. #### Localização dos ficheiros

   Para armazenar correctamente os ficheiros dos tipos de letra que vais utilizar, os mesmos deverão ficar dentro da seguinte localização no teu projecto:

   ```
   /assets/fonts
   ```

   Deverás já ter a `/assets`, faltando criar a sub-pasta `/fonts`.
2. #### Formatos dos ficheiros

   Existem dois formatos suportados [**TTF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) e [**OTF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType), sendo o primeiro o mais recomendado por questões de compatibilidade, apesar de ambos funcionarem.

   **Nota:**
   O ficheiro e a sua extensão tem que estar com letras minúsculas:

   ```
   minha_fonte.ttf (correcto)
   minha_fonte.TTF (incorrecto)
   minha_Fonte.ttf (incorrecto)
   Museo.otf       (incorrecto) terá que ficar museo.otf
   ```
3. #### Criar XML para nomear propriedades personalizadas

   O Android SDK permite que nomeies propriedades personalizadas para os teus *widgets*, mas para isso é preciso criar um XML na localização em baixo com o nome `attrs.xml`:

   ```
   /res/values
   ```

   O XML a criar terá o seguinte código:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
       <attr name="minhaFonte" format="string" />
     </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
4. ### Layout

   Podemos agora elaborar o *layout* que deverá estar presente no ficheiro `activity_main.xml` no localização em baixo indicada:

   ```
   /res/layout/activity_main.xml
   ```

   Nesse ficheiro aplicamos o seguinte código:

   ```xml
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:padding="12dp"
       android:text="Fonte padrão do Android" />

     <com.authorwjf.customfontdemo.MyTextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="32sp"
       android:padding="12dp"
       customfontdemo:minhaFonte="minha_fonte.ttf"
       android:text="A minha fonte no Android" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   Como dá para ver, já estamos a fazer da propriedade personalizada `fontName`.
5. ### Classe

   Falta agora criar uma classe em baixo com o nome `MyTextView` que vai estender a *text view* padrão, devendo o ficheiro ficar na seguinte localização:

   ```
   /src
   ```

   Com o nome da classe que estamos a criar:

   ```
   /src/MyTextView.java
   ```

   Contendo o seguinte código:

   ```java
   package com.authorwjf.customfontdemo;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.res.TypedArray;
   import android.graphics.Typeface;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MyTextView extends TextView {

     public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       init(attrs);
     }

     public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init(attrs);
     }

     public MyTextView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init(null);
     }

     private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
       if (attrs!=null) {
         TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
         String minhaFonte = a.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_minhaFonte);

         if (minhaFonte!=null) {
           Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+minhaFonte);
           setTypeface(myTypeface);
         }

         a.recycle();
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Aqui estamos a recolher o nome da fonte do atributo personalizado e a aplicar o [*typeface*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html).
6. ### MainActivity.java

   Dado que o *text view* está num ambiente independente, não precisamos de fazer modificações ao ficheiro `MainActivity.java` localizado na pasta em baixo indicada:

   ```
   /src/MainActivity.java
   ```

   Cujo mesmo terá o seguinte código:

   ```java
   package com.authorwjf.customfontdemo;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }
   }
   ```

Temos assim concluída uma aplicação em Android que faz uso dum tipo de letra que não o padrão do sistema.

[Link para download dos ficheiros.](http://b2b.cbsimg.net/downloads/Weilage/custom_font_demo.zip)

---

#### Créditos

Créditos deste tutorial passo a passo para o [William J. Francis](http://www.techrepublic.com/search/?a=william%20j.%20francis) no site [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com) no seguinte tópico:

[Pro tip: Extend Android's TextView to use custom fonts](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-extend-androids-textview-to-use-custom-fonts/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Eis aqui uma ótima biblioteca para isso ok.

https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView

Answer (score 0):

Utilizarei como exemplo a fonte **orange_juice**.

Primeiro de tudo: Crie a pasta assets em app/src/main/assets... Caso tenha dificuldade para localizar, mude a visualização do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cole a fonte que deseja na pasta **assets** (arquivo .ttf ou .otf).

No método onCreate coloque o seguinte:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "orange_juice.ttf");
        tv01.setTypeface(font);

    }
}
```

O código é bem simples na realidade.

Perceba que a classe **TypeFace** tem o método **createFromAsset**. Ele recebe como parâmetro a pasta default dos assets e o nome do arquivo de fonte a ser utilizado.

Vale ressaltar que quando se fala de fontes customizáveis, tenha sempre em mente que elas podem não funcionar corretamente, principalmente se ela não possuir todos os caracteres especiais que a aplicação pode vir a exigir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**FONTE** => http://www.mobits.com.br/2011/5/20/personalizando-fontes-no-android

FIM!